# Topsy Tweets and Arabic (curl)

Tags: url, curl, twitter, arabic, topsy

I am using the following URL to get all tweets that mention the farsi/arabic word **"سلام"** though the Topsy API:

http://otter.topsy.com/search.json?q=سلام&page=1&perpage=100&mintime=1244160000&maxtime=1244163600&apikey=FAF7F2D0D8A143978CB7762CE35FCF99

However, The results I get are as follows:

`{"request":{"parameters":{"page":"1","q":"سلام","maxtime":"1244163600","perpage":"100","mintime":"1244160000"},"response_type":"json","resource":"search","url":"http://otter.topsy.com/search.json?maxtime=1244163600&mintime=1244160000&page=1&perpage=100&q=%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85"},"response":{"window":"custom","page":1,"total":0,"perpage":100,"last_offset":0,"hidden":0,"list":[],"offset":0}}`

The foreign word: "سلام" is read by the API as: %D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85 and thus no results are yielded. Any suggestions on what to do would be much appreciated!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of them are equivalent. `%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85` is the [HTML encoded version](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp).

Comment: Thanks. I realized after posting this. My other question is this: #

I was running a shell script that looks like this: The search words are farsi and the other variables are correct as well. But it will not connect. Would you know what the problem is?
curl "http://otter.topsy.com/search.json?q="${searchwords}"&page="$j"&perpage=100&mintime="${mintime}"&maxtime="${maxtime}"&apikey=FAF7F2D0D8A143978CB7762CE35FCF99"

Comment: remove the `"` from query strings. curl will encode the strings automatically before sending them. Also you can search twitter this way: http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=KeyWord